# Query that allow duplicate values in a table but not for same foreign key reference

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using SQL Server2005 with asp.net. I want validation at server side to restrict duplicate entries, Here i am using two tables companies and Branches. In Branches Table i had maintain a foreign key of CompanyId. In Branches the BranchName can be duplicate but not for the Particular CompanyId.

```
Companies Table:
        Columns: CompanyId (Primary Key), CompanyName

Branches Table :
        Columns: BranchId(Primary Key), BranchName, CompanyId (Foreign Key).
```

Company Id can be Repeat multiple times, one to many Relationship.
Which query I use to that allow duplicate but not for the same CompanyId?

Answer (score 4):

You want a constraint that enforces uniqueness against both the CompanyID and BranchName columns. This can either by the primary key for the table (as Tim has recommended), or a UNIQUE constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Branches ADD
    CONSTRAINT UQ_BranchNamesWithinCompanies UNIQUE (BranchName,CompanyID);
```

You can decide which order to put the columns within the constraint, based on how frequently searches are performed in the table based on the two columns. I.e. you're actually creating an index on these columns, so you may as well use it to improve some query performance.

The above ordering was based on a guess that you might search for branch names without reference to a particular company. If you're always searching within a company, and are performing prefix searches (e.g. `CompanyID=21 and BranchName like 'Lon%'`), then you'd want to reverse the order of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [composite primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236.aspx) from BranchName+CompanyId.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx

Comment: Company Id can be Repeat multiple times.

Comment: @Ritu: yes and your problem is... ??
You could use Damiens solution with unique contsraints or my solution with a composite primary key. Both will avoiding duplicates(same BranchName for same CompanyID). Your question now is how to query that already a given combination exists in Database? You could either try to insert it and catch the constraint exception what would be the simpliest way or write a query that looks into the table before the insert(slower).

Comment: Actually my condition is for a single company there may be number of branches but for the same company it should be the same branchname, and for a different company the branchname can be same (eg. there are 2 companies like A and B and branchname like x and y. Here i want to say for A branchname can be both x and y, but x must not be repeated for A, but repeat for B.